# Can not access data of useQuery result - _rawValue - Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError | Vue 3 Apollo 4

Tags: async-await, vuejs3, pinia, vue-apollo

I'm trying a simple API request with Vue 3 and Apollo 4 with the composition API. I want to get the backend data into a pinia store, so I have the API call in the store under actions {}. Then I want to process the data in the same function.

The backend shows the correct request and vue receives the correct data in the result._rawValue, but I can't access it while code execution.

`store.js`:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia"
import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { ALL_BLOGS } from "@/queries";

export const useBlogStore = defineStore({
  id: "BlogStore",
  state: () => ({
    blog_api: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    getAllBlogs() {
        const { result } = useQuery(ALL_BLOGS)
        console.log('store test')
        console.log(result) // returns Ref
        console.log('store test end')

        this.blog_api = result.allBlogs.map(item => item.name) // process data
    },
  },

});
```

Fetching data only in a component does also not work. Just fetch and process the data, without using the store.
component.vue

```
<template>
<v-container>
  <v-row>
    <!-- does not work -->
    {{ blogs }}
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <!-- does work -->
    {{ result.allBlogs.map(item => item.name) }}
  </v-row>
</v-container>
</template>
<script setup>
import { useBlogStore } from "@/store/store"
import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { computed } from "vue"
import { ALL_BLOGS } from "@/queries"

const BlogStore = useBlogStore();

const { result } = useQuery(ALL_BLOGS);
const blogs = computed(() => result.allBlogs.map(item => item.name));

</script>
```

From what I understand, the `useQuery` result is a ref and when I want to access the result, it is not yet there. When I add `async ... await` before the `useQuery`, the editor tells me, `useQuery` is already an asynchronous function and `await` has no effect here. Couldn't work it out with computed, watchers or .then

Not that good with JavaScript, some help would be nice. Do I have to wait for useQuery to finish the request or for the Ref variable to update properly? And how would I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/apollo/issues/1219#issuecomment-981130424

Comment: thx @yoduh So useQuery is not for fetching data and working with it? What is the general approach? I would guess it is something normal to fetch data and work with it, why can I not use the intended useQuery with computed?

Answer (score 0):

So my JavaScript knowledge is just too poor I guess. This does work:

`const blogs = computed(() => result.value?.allBlogs.map(item => item.name) ?? []);`

And this does not:

`const blogs = computed(() => result.allBlogs.map(item => item.name));`

Can someone tell me what the difference is? Why can I use the second in the template, but not in the setup and why is the first ok to use in the setup?

Comment: It's about the Composition API more specially the reactive state in Vue 3. Inside the `script setup` you need also the `.value` property to mutate/output but inside templates **refs** are automatically unwrapped. Read more: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref